# CartoD3 chart not displaying - CartoDB

Tags: carto, d3, chart

I have tornados table with columns damage,date,month . I used the following code to create a barchart .

> ```
>       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
>         <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
>         <head>
>         <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
>         <title>D3 Visualization API Sample</title>
>         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js">       </script>
>         script type="text/javascript" src="libs/underscore-1.1.6.js"></script>
>         <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/backbone.js"></script>
>         <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/d3.min.js"></script>
>         <script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.cartodb.js"></script>
>         <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.cartodb.js"></script>
>         <link href='css/cartodb.d3.default.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
>         <style type="text/css">
>         #cartodb_d3 {
>         float: left; width: 800px;
>          }
>         </style>
>        <script type="text/javascript">
>         var CartoDB = Backbone.CartoDB({user: 'praveensimbu'});
>         var tor = CartoDB.CartoDBCollection.extend({
>         sql: function() {
>         return "select month,damage as magnitude from tor group by month order by month     asc";
>          }
>          });
>          var eq = new tor();
> ```

```
       var CartoD3 = Backbone.CartoD3(eq);
       $(document).ready(function() {
        var barchart = new CartoD3.BarChart({ el: $("#cartodb_d3"), variable:      'magnitude', label: 'month', title: "damage by tornados"});
});
       </script>
        </head>
       <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
       <div id="cartodb_d3"></div>
       </body>
        </html>
```

But When I run it, the chart is not displayed, instead I am getting the below as result.

[image]

Please let me know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is ok in your code except this statement:

```
"select month, damage as magnitude from tor group by month order by month asc"
```

At first glance, this SQL query seems ok, but it isn't.

Your browser already told you that the code have the following error:

```
{"error":["column \"tor.damage\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"]}
```

I know that because I've tested [the code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13060205/Stackexchange/Damage_By_Tornados/index01.html) with my browser.

By opening the debugging tools (*Developer Tools*) built into your browser (in my case, using "*Ctrl + Shift + I*", because I'm working with *Chrome*) you will see something similar to this:

[image]

The error indicates us two ways to follow.

---

Let's explore [the first one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13060205/Stackexchange/Damage_By_Tornados/index02.html), and put the damage column in the GROUP BY clause:

```
"select month, damage as magnitude from tor group by month, damage order by month asc"
```

[image]

Obviously, this is working, but, I wonder, is this what you are looking for?

---

Well, maybe it's better to explore [the second way](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13060205/Stackexchange/Damage_By_Tornados/index03.html), and to use an aggregate function (avg, max, min, sum, etc.), which [compute a single result from a set of input values](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
"select month, sum(damage) as magnitude from tor group by month order by month asc"
```

I think this result must be closer to your expectations:

[image]

I leave you the pleasure to identify a function to meets your requirements.